# How to add Loop invariant to limit or bound integers in frama-c? (preconditions to bound integers)

Tags: c, frama-c

Using frama-c, I need to analyse Euclid's algorithm for computing greatest common divisor between two numbers with Bezozut coefficients. The algorithm takes two positive integers *x* and *y* as input and calculates two integers s and t such that
*s · x + t · y = gcd(x, y)*

When I run the code using

> frama-c-gui -val euclidEVA.c

to analyse, I have some unsigned overflow & out of bounds write alarms generated.

```
///*@
    //requires ...
//*/
int main(int x, int y, int* pp, int* qp) 
{
    int s = 1, t = 0, u = 0, v = 1;
    ///*@
          //loop invariant ...
    //*/
    while(y > 0)
    {
        int r = x % y;
        int q = x / y;
        x = y; 
                y = r;
        int w = u;
                u = s - u * q; 
                s = w;
                w = v;
        v = t - v * q;
        t = w;

    }   
    *pp = s; *qp = t;
    return x;
}
```

- What precondition can I add to validate the memory access?
- What loop invariant can I add to limit *s* and *t*?
- What loop invariant can I add to bound *u* and *v*?
- What precondition can I add for the bounds of *x* and *y* at the beginning?
- Any comments on the alarms (signed overflow & out of bounds write) generated please?

[screenshot of Alarms generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQWOR.png)

Thanks.

Comment: Well, you have the preconditions exactly spelled for you in the  "alarms". `assert  <precondition is here>`. What more do you need? Add `assert(the precondition);` to the code.

Comment: @KamilCuk this is not completely true: the `assert` expresses something that must hold at a precise point in the function body. `requires`, and the other hand, puts a constraint on the state in which the function is entered. There are relations between the two, of course, but in the general case, you can't take the alarm and put it as a pre-condition.